# LINQ Query Not Selecting Files

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to LINQ query a set of files where I can find the file names with a specific string in them.

I was using:

```
var docs = directory.enumerateFiles(searchFolder, "* " + strNumber+ "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
```

That was working fine, but some of my file searches were taking 30+ minutes due to the fact that one of the directories has 1+ million files. I was hoping to speed up the search process with a PLINQ query. However, while my syntax is good, I'm not getting the results I would expect. It looks like my problem may be in the Where statement. Any help would be helpful.

```
foreach (strNumber in strNumbers) 
{
    DirectoryInfo searchDirectory = new DirectoryInfo(searchFolder);
    IEnumerable<System.IO.FileInfo> allDocs = searchDirectory.EnumerateFiles("*", SearchOPtion.AllDirectories);

    IEnumerable<System.IO.FileInfo> docsToProcess = strNumbers
        .SelectMany(strNumber => allDocs
        .Where(file => file.Name.Contains(strNumber)))
        .Distinct();
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: What is the difference in the results you are getting and the results you expect?

Comment: I am not getting any results. I am expecting to get any document with the strNumber in it to be collected so I can use it like below.

Comment: foreach (var docToProcess in docsToProcess) {}

Comment: So for example, before I was getting xxx_strNumber_xxx.docs and now I'm not getting any of those documents.

Comment: With that many files you will probably need to utilize an indexing solution, like maybe Lucene.Net.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would change the order of the problem.

1. Create a list of all files (into memory)
2. Perform the search over the memory list

Then, you can use a Parallel Foreach over the memory array and your disk usage is limited to the initial search.

```cs
var searchDirectory = new DirectoryInfo(searchFolder);
var allDocs = searchDirectory.EnumerateFiles("*", SearchOPtion.AllDirectories).ToArray();

// For extra points, use a Parallel.ForEach here for multi-threaded work
Parallel.Foreach(strNumbers, strNumber => 
{
   // Work on allDocs here, it should be in memory
});
```

Comment: I love the idea of this solution. My concern is that there will be a race issue.  In the Parallel.ForEach statement, I will be creating a string of file names to be used to copy the files found to another folder. I don't know how to negate the race issue. Do you have a suggestion as to how to do that?

For example:

Parallel.Foreach (strNumbers, strNumber =>
{
    // Get string of files to copy
    // Create the roboCopy string (using this to multithread and log the copy procedure)
    // Copy files to new folders
}

Comment: Can always make a List of jobs to perform during the `Parallel.ForEach` and then run the copy operations afterwards?